# How to expand this expression

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I want to expand $|\langle a,b\rangle + \langle c,d\rangle |^2$.

$|\langle a,b\rangle + \langle c,d\rangle |^2=|\langle a,b\rangle |^2 + |\langle c,d\rangle |^2 + 2|\langle a,b\rangle ||\langle c,d\rangle |$.

Is this correct? If not, what would be the correct way to expand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not completely correct, the Skalar Product is just a number so normal rules like binomial rules apply but you got a triangle inequality in there:

$$|\langle a,b\rangle +\langle c,d\rangle|^2\le(|\langle a,b\rangle|+|\langle c,d\rangle |)^2=|\langle a,b\rangle|^2+2|\langle a,b\rangle||\langle c,d\rangle|+|\langle c,d\rangle|^2$$

So it holds as an inequality but not an equality